# Is there any working solution for getting average color of an url image in react-native expo?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, background-color, react-color

I just want to get average color of an image and paint my background with that color. But because of I'm using expo in react native I can not find any solution for this.

What should I do to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like no way to achieve that using `expo`, you have one of these option ethers drop `expo` and move to `react native` or use your backend to get the average color.

If You're using `React-Native` can get the base64 from the image and use [react-native-image-colors](https://github.com/osamaqarem/react-native-image-colors) to get the average color from it like this example:

```
const result = await ImageColors.getColors(uri, {
  fallback: '#228B22',
  cache: true,
  key: 'unique_key',
})
```

you can check the full documentation on github from [here](https://github.com/osamaqarem/react-native-image-colors).

Comment: Yeah, I know this but this is just a lie. If you dig into it, you will see that the repo owner is saying in the github form that "Not supported in expo". I tried it and yeah not works.

Comment: Did you try doing it using javascript?

Comment: Yeah, still not working.

Comment: can you share your code in https://snack.expo.dev/

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@alpovka/nervous-chocolates. It is just my card component that I want to change background according to image on it.

Comment: It looks like no way to achieve that using expo, you have one of these option ethers drop expo and move to react native or use your backend to get the average color.
I'll update my answer and hope you accept it as a correct answer